# R function to find the sum of c given the column values

Tags: r

I want to create a function that I can simulate n number of times. My ultimate goal is to find if the sum of c for every n number of simulations. I am a beginner in r-coding so I am just starting to practice with for loops and if else statements.

This is what I hope to achieve as of now: If a> b, c would be "2" and if a < b, c would be "-2". If a=b, c would be determined by the a and b value of the NEXT row. This is what i have so far, but I am keep getting errors. I would like to know if what I have for a=b is how I should approach this. Any help is appreciated.

```
a<-c(5,6,7,8,9,10,1,4,6,7)
b<-c(4,6,8,5,3,4,5,2,1,3)
c<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

df<-data.frame(a,b,c)

if(df$a > df$b){
  df$c<- c(2)}
  
  else if(df$a < df$b){
    df$c<- c(-2)}
  
  else if(df$a == df$b){ # a=b
        
    if(df$a[+1,] > df$b[+1,]) {
          df$c<- c(2)}
    else(df$a[+1,] < df$b[+1,]){
      df$c<- c(-2) }
  }
  else
print("error")

}

sum(df$c)
```

Comment: what if in case of a == b the next row is **still** a == b? You could look into recursion....

Answer (score 2):

#### The problem

`if()` and `else()` in R is meant for control flow, and is not vectorized. In plain English this means that `if()` is expecting a statement evaluating to **one** `TRUE` or `FALSE`. When you do `df$a > df$b` you get a boolean vector of the same length as rows in your dataframe. When this happens, `if()` will only use the first item, and give you a warning. This will give you the wrong answers.

#### A better solution

I think you are looking for `ifelse()` which is vectorized. And since you have nested if-else statements you are probably better off with `dplyr::case_when()`.

Here is an example which also fixes cases where `a == b` for multiple rows:

```r
# Note that I've added two consecutive rows where a == b
a <- c(5,6,6,7,8,9,10,1,4,6,7)
b <- c(4,6,6,8,5,3,4,5,2,1,3)

df <- data.frame(a, b)


library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    c = case_when(
      a > b ~  2,
      a < b ~ -2,
      #  If not a > b nor a < b is TRUE, they must be equal, 
      # so we set all other cases to NA...
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    )
  ) %>% 
  # ... and then we use fill() to replace NAs with the first 
  # non NA valua after it
  tidyr::fill(c, .direction = "up")

#>     a b  c
#> 1   5 4  2
#> 2   6 6 -2
#> 3   6 6 -2
#> 4   7 8 -2
#> 5   8 5  2
#> 6   9 3  2
#> 7  10 4  2
#> 8   1 5 -2
#> 9   4 2  2
#> 10  6 1  2
#> 11  7 3  2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

##### How this works:

- `ifelse()` works like `if()` and `else()` in your code, but it accepts multiple values
- `case_when()` acts like nested `ifelse()` statements, so it will first check if `a > b` and set those values equal to `2`, next it will check the remaining rows if `a < b` and set those to `-2` and so on.
- In cases where a is not less nor more than b, they must be equal. We set these cases to `NA`.
- After we use `tidyr::fill()` to replace missing values with the first instance of a non-missing value after it. This handles cases where there are multiple consecutive rows of `a == b`.

Comment: You need to use `lead()` instead of `lag()` since OP wants `c` to be based on the next row in case of equality. Also, lead/lag only work if you know that there cannot be multiple rows in a row where `a == b`

Comment: Thanks, you're right. The `lag()`/`lead()` was a silly mistake on my behalf, and I failed to consider the cases where you have multiple rows of `a == b`. I've updated my answer to how I would solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: two users already pointed out what to do if there's consecutive rows of a == b. Good opportunity to dive into the tidyverse (as already suggested by others):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  a = c(5,6,7,8,9,10,1,4,6,7),
  b = c(4,6,8,5,3,4,5,2,1,3)
)

df %>%
  mutate(c = ifelse(a == b, NA, 2 * sign(a-b))) %>% ## (1)
  fill(c, .direction = 'up') ## (2)
```

(1) set c to NA when a == b
(2) 'fill' (replace) NAs with the next availabe value down the rows

Starting with R, it's helpful to know that *[vectorizing](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/04/vectorization-in-r-why/)* (the `x[n]` thing) *usually makes your code conciser* and—in certain situations— much faster than using loops. In your case:

```
df$c <- 2 * sign(df$a - df$b) ## see ?sign
z <- df$c == 0 ## see (1)
df$c[z] = lead(df$c,1)[z] ## see (2)
```

(1) equal numbers have sign zero, z is a boolean vector indicating the positions (rows) where a == b (thus: z is TRUE)
(2) change c *only* at the positions where z is TRUE. `lead` and `lag` are functions taking a vector and returning its shifted (by a given number of positions) vector.

Comment: Using `lead()` assumes that the cannot be multiple cases in a row where `a == b`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. This will also work with multiple equal `a` and `b` in series (I have added row 3 to the data to demonstrate).

It relies on `cumsum()` to group the data, such that rows with `a == b` are in the same group as the next row that is `a != b`. Then it sets `c` to the last value in the group.

```r
library(tidyverse) 

a<-c(5,6,5,7,8,9,10,1,4,6,7)
b<-c(4,6,5,8,5,3,4,5,2,1,3)

df <-data.frame(a,b)

df |> 
  mutate(c = ifelse(a>b, 2, -2), # Determines c for `a != b` cases
         grp = rev(cumsum(rev(a != b)))) |> # create group variable, use rev() since we want backward cumsum
  group_by(grp) |> 
  mutate(c = last(c)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(-grp)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>        a     b     c
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     5     4     2
#>  2     6     6    -2
#>  3     5     5    -2
#>  4     7     8    -2
#>  5     8     5     2
#>  6     9     3     2
#>  7    10     4     2
#>  8     1     5    -2
#>  9     4     2     2
#> 10     6     1     2
#> 11     7     3     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: looks like the base pipe operator is making its way into the wild - nice!